# PHP - Get bool to echo false when false

Tags: php, boolean

The following code doesn't print out anything:

```
$bool_val = (bool)false;
echo $bool_val;
```

But the following code prints `1`:

```
$bool_val = (bool)true;
echo $bool_val;
```

Is there a better way to print `0` or `false` when `$bool_val` is `false` than adding an `if` statement?

Comment: If this is for debugging, try var_dump instead of echo.

Comment: The `(bool)` cast is redundant, you don't need to cast bool to bool: `(bool) true === true`.

Comment: Is there a way to configure PHP so that  `echo 0==1;` outputs `0` or `false`?

Answer (score 301, accepted):

```
echo $bool_val ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Or if you only want output when it's false:

```
echo !$bool_val ? 'false' : '';
```

Comment: It's confusing, sprawling & unhelpful without any apparent benefit. I've been programming for 20+ years and *never* have I wanted 'false' to auto-convert to blank.. null many times, but never 'false'. My Java/Spring/Hibernate development is so so so much cleaner & stronger than even modest PHP systems. **I could find plenty of people who were confused..** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042002/php-printed-boolean-value-is-empty-why **but I couldn't find any reference as to a real _reason_ for this design "feature".**

Comment: I really wanted to argue why (string)FALSE == "" is a good idea based on this bit from PHP's documentation: "A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values." but I tested it out, and (bool)"0" also evaluates to FALSE, so... I dunno. I love PHP, but I can't deny that that's kinda' weird >_>

Comment: It isn't weird that `FALSE == ''`. It's perfectly valid and a part of other languages, including javascript. What's weird is FALSE defaults to an empty string. It should default to 0. Always. Especially since TRUE will always default to 1. This breaks a cardinal rule of programming. Keep your code consistent. This is clearly a bug.

Comment: While this is the simplest way to do this, running an array through print_r that contains boolean values, those values will show blank unless you previously run the array through a loop that swaps them out, so if you're just trying to debug or log, it becomes a giant pain in the neck to see if the values are actually true or false or something else that looks blank.

Comment: @Ben although `!! '0'` evaluates to `false` in PHP, it's `true` in JS. `!! ""` is false in JS and PHP.

Answer (score 85):

This is the easiest way to do this:

```
$text = var_export($bool_value,true);
echo $text;
```

or

```
var_export($bool_value)
```

If the second argument is not true, it will output the result directly.

Comment: Thank you. There is no need to make a stupid language even weirder. Even in php there are workarounds to make it sort of okay.

Answer (score 54):

This will print out boolean value as it is, instead of 1/0.

```
    $bool = false;

    echo json_encode($bool);   //false
```

Comment: Great answer, especially if you exactly need that boolean in JSON!

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: simple and effective! needed this for some GraphQL

Answer (score 34):

No, since the other option is modifying the Zend engine, and one would be hard-pressed to call that a "better way".

**Edit:**

If you really wanted to, you could use an array:

```
$boolarray = Array(false => 'false', true => 'true');
echo $boolarray[false];
```

Comment: That's a weird way to do it, because array keys cannot be bool types. PHP will cast that to array(0 => 'false', 1 => 'true').

Comment: @mehaase: I've long ago stopped trying to apply any sort of logic towards PHP's type-handling. I just take it as it comes.

Answer (score 25):

[`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) provides the desired functionality.

This will *always* print a value rather than printing nothing for `null` or `false`. `var_export` prints a PHP representation of the argument it's passed, the output could be copy/pasted back into PHP.

```php
var_export(true);    // true
var_export(false);   // false
var_export(1);       // 1
var_export(0);       // 0
var_export(null);    // NULL
var_export('true');  // 'true'   <-- note the quotes
var_export('false'); // 'false'
```

If you want to print strings `"true"` or `"false"`, you can cast to a boolean as below, but beware of the peculiarities:

```php
var_export((bool) true);   // true
var_export((bool) false);  // false
var_export((bool) 1);      // true
var_export((bool) 0);      // false
var_export((bool) '');     // false
var_export((bool) 'true'); // true
var_export((bool) null);   // false

// !! CAREFUL WITH CASTING !!
var_export((bool) 'false'); // true
var_export((bool) '0');     // false
```

Answer (score 23):

Try converting your boolean to an integer?

```
 echo (int)$bool_val;
```

Comment: Hah... simple. Perfect.

Answer (score 23):

I like this one to print that out

```
var_dump ($var);
```

Answer (score 6):

The `%b` option of [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) will convert a boolean to an integer:

```
echo sprintf("False will print as %b", false); //False will print as 0
echo sprintf("True will print as %b", true); //True will print as 1
```

If you're not familiar with it: You can give this function an arbitrary amount of parameters while the first one should be your ouput string spiced with replacement strings like `%b` or `%s` for general string replacement.

Each pattern will be replaced by the argument in order:

```
echo sprintf("<h1>%s</h1><p>%s<br/>%s</p>", "Neat Headline", "First Line in the paragraph", "My last words before this demo is over");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
echo(var_export($var));
```

When `$var` is boolean variable, `true` or `false` will be printed out.

Comment: In my opinion, the best solution when exporting PHP variables in JavaScript !

Comment: This is a bit misleading. `var_export` in this case will echo its result and return null, so var_export is outputting the `true || false`, and `echo` is echoing `null` (`''`). To return the output from `var_export`, you need to supply a second parameter as `true`.

Comment: @RPDeshaies if you want to export php variables to javascript `json_encode` is a better option.

Answer (score 6):

This gives `0` or `1`:

```php
intval($bool_val);
```

[PHP Manual: intval function](http://php.net/intval)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ternary operator

```
echo false ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Answer (score 3):

Your'e casting a boolean to boolean and expecting an integer to be displayed.  It works for `true` but not false.  Since you expect an integer:

```
echo (int)$bool_val;
```

Answer (score 2):

json_encode will do it out-of-the-box, but it's not pretty (indented, etc):

```
echo json_encode(array('whatever' => TRUE, 'somethingelse' => FALSE));
```

...gives...

```
{"whatever":true,"somethingelse":false}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want debug an array:

```
function debug_array($a){
    return array_map(function($v){
        return is_bool($v) ? ($v ? 'true' : 'false') : $v;
    }, $a);
}
```

To use it:

```
$arr = debug_array(['test' => true, 'id' => false]);
print_r($arr); // output Array ( [test] => true [id] => false )
```