# PHP printed boolean value is empty, why?

Tags: php, boolean, echo

I am new to PHP. I am implementing a script and I am puzzled by the following:

```
$local_rate_filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ghjr324l.txt";
$local_rates_file_exists = file_exists($local_rate_filename);

echo $local_rates_file_exists."<br>";
```

This piece of code displays an empty string, rather than 0 or 1 (or true or false). Why? Documentation seems to indicate that a boolean value is always 0 or 1. What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Have you tried to echo the `file_exists($local_rate_filename);` directly? I am curious.

Comment: A simple echo (without casting to int) prints a empty string.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Be careful when you convert back and forth with boolean, [the manual says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting):

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is
> converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and
> forth between boolean and string values.

So you need to do a:

```
echo (int)$local_rates_file_exists."<br>";
```

Answer (score 24):

About converting a boolean to a string, [the manual *actually* says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting):

> A boolean **TRUE** value is converted to the string "1". Boolean **FALSE** is converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values.

A boolean can always be *represented* as a 1 or a 0, but that's not what you get when you convert it to a string.

If you want it to be represented as an integer, [cast it to one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting):

```
$intVar = (int) $boolVar;
```

Comment: +1 "This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values."  That would have been also the case if FALSE were converted instead to "0". But, I guess, that would be too consistent, and PHP always tries hard to surprise the programmer.

Comment: It is possible to write a web application in PHP, but it is also possible to hike a mile in a foot of snow in your socks.

Answer (score 1):

The results come from the fact that php implicitly converts bool values to strings if used like in your example. `(string)false` gives an empty string and `(string)true` gives `'1'`. That is consistent with the fact that `'' == false` and `'1' == true`.

Comment: No, it does not from what I can see. No <br> (line break) is printed.

Comment: Run php -a in console. Then do  echo false."<br>";  and  echo true."<br>";. Btw. sry that I edited the post so that your comment has lost the context. I had done it before I have read this.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna check if the file exists when your are not sure of the return type is true/false or 0/1 you could use ===.

```
if($local_rates_file_exists === true)
{
   echo "the file exists";
}
else
{
   echo "the doesnt file exists";
}
```

Comment: php > echo (int)(true === 1);
    0