# Booleon in objects (classes)

Tags: php, oop, variables, boolean

This is something I don't understand. If I assign the variable `$bool` the value `true`, and then later in the code change it to `false`, the variable `$bool` looses its value?

*FYI: This reassignment of values is happening in a function in the class.*

```
class csvcheck {
    function booleonChange () {
        echo "<br>";
        $bool = true;
        echo "1. assignment of booleon: " . $bool ."<br>";
        $bool = false;
        echo "2. assignment of booleon: " .$bool . "<br>"; // value of $bool is lost. Why??
    }
}

$csv = new csvcheck;
$csv->booleonChange();
```

If this code is executed in the browser, you will see this:

1. assignment of booleon: 1
2. assignment of booleon:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i remember correctly, the PHP boolean false is actually converted to an empty string rather than the value of 0 that I believe you are looking for.

Actually just looked for it, and this seems to confirm:

[PHP printed boolean value is empty, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042002/php-printed-boolean-value-is-empty-why)