# Decoding recaptcha return values

Tags: php, recaptcha

I've got a [reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) service working, but passing the return values through PHP's `json_decode` function gives some results I don't understand.

If the reCaptcha is valid then the service returns `{ "success": true }` - which I expect.

Calling

```
print_r(json_decode($result, $assoc = true)); //where $result is the service call
```

gives

```
Array ( [success] => )
```

...but I was expecting `Array ( [success] => 1)` (or similar), to signify a `true` value.

In fact, `print_r(json_decode('{"success": true}', $assoc = true));` *does* return `Array ( [success] => 1 )`

What's different about the json the reCaptcha is returning? (and / or what am I failing to understand?!)

I guess that's what's further confusion here:

```
echo(gettype($a->success));
echo($a->success === true);
echo($a->success === false);
```

then I get

```
boolean
1
1
```

How can a check against `true` and `false` both return `true`?!

***Further info***

Even more confusingly (for me at least), I've tried `var_dump` too:

```
echo($a);
var_dump($a);
```

which returns

```
{ "success": true }
string(22) "{ "success": false }"
```

why is the json representation in `var_dump` `false` when `echo` shows that it is `true`?!

Comment: personally i used this lib: https://github.com/google/recaptcha

Comment: @Dagon thanks, that looks interesting.  I'm still curious about why the returned json doesn't get decoded in the same way as my plain text version does tho!

Comment: im not paid enough to work out why, i stop at - well that works, move on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my question, I should have probably said I was using code inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30749288/889604), and that my call to the Google verification service was wrapped in a function.  I've realised that you can only ever call this service once, but I was calling it every time I called the function, and so the second time I called the function (i.e. the second time I called the service), the verification service *did* return `false`

I'm not sure this is explicitly documented anywhere, although perhaps it should have been a bit more obvious!

Answer (score 1):

I think, your main problem was that the JSON returned from recaptcha and saved in `$result` was `{ "success": false }`and not `{ "success": true }`.

That would explain why you got `Array ( [success] => )` and not `Array ( [success] => 1)` as `echo false` [returns an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042002/php-printed-boolean-value-is-empty-why) but `echo true` returns 1;

I tried to reproduce the response from recaptcha using this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="FILL_IN_YOUR_KEY"></div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$data = ['secret' => 'FILL_IN_YOUR_SECRET', 'response' => $_GET['g-recaptcha-response']];

$options = ['http' => ['method' => 'POST', 'content' => http_build_query($data),],];
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo '$result var_dump:<br>';
var_dump($result);
echo '$result print_r:<br>';
print_r($result);
$object = json_decode($result);
echo '<br><br><br>$object var_dump:<br>';
print_r($object);
echo '<br>$object print_r:<br>';
var_dump($object);
```

**And what I got was this in case of success:**

[image: In case of success]

**And this in case of failure:**

[image: In case of failure]

Comment: Yeh - that's as far as I'd got! I couldn't see why I'd got a `false` value too. I've found out why (it was *really* stupid) and added it as an answer