# PHP / mysqli does not echo single zero

Tags: php, apache

This is a strange bug I've come across when switching my code over from 000webhost to ipage. It's the same code and a consistently different result.

The following example does nothing.

```
echo 0;
```

This example gives us '00'

```
echo 0;
echo 0;
```

Comment: `var_dump` your `mysqli_fetch_row` and show us.

Comment: Why are you using `AS count` if you're not using it?

Comment: @OPatel: var_dump: array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: @user2588666 Try `var_dump($count[0]);`

Comment: `echo $count['count'];`

Comment: @user2588666 can you post the view source of the html page, make sure it isn't hidden in there.

Comment: add die; statement after echo $count[0];

Comment: @OPatel: var_dump($count[0]); : string(1) "0"

Comment: @Arian: The expected result isn't hidden in the source, thanks.  It works fine when the count is 1, for example.

Comment: @GonzaloBahamondez: I've tried exit; right afterwards, and it didn't work.

Comment: @user2588666 `var_dump` is showing that there is a string value in there. Are you showing all errors?

Comment: Can you add : $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or mysqli_error($co); In Phpmyadmin do you have some result ?

Comment: @Opatel: If interested, please see my edit.

Comment: It's probably an issue with your database (to me 000webhost is really bad...)

Comment: @Dev'Hamz: In phpmyadmin, I do have the correct result.  However, my best guess is currently it has something to do with the webserver not liking to return just 0.  As you can see in my edit, echo 0 does nothing, but echo 0 twice echoes it twice.  My previous web host didn't do this.

Comment: @Dev'Hamz: Took the words out of my mouth :)

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, or get as results. You're doing an `AS count` Are you aware of what using an alias does, or is for?

Comment: This is NOT a MySQL issue. It can be replicated without even touching MySQL so this has NOTHING to do with MySQL.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: The use of the alias is irrelevant to the issue.  I get your point, but it doesn't make a difference.  The alias was previously used, but I made the code more concise for posting it on here.  The problem is simply that on this web host, when you try to echo 0, nothing happens. When you try to echo 1, it works. When you try to echo 00, it works. So, these "issues" are separate.  Thank you for taking a look at it, though.

Comment: Using `echo 0; exit;` doesn't work neither? It works on my server.

Comment: @user2588666 you will keep getting these requests until you change your question to remove MySQL and probably get rid of your MySQL example. You should really be focusing on your follow up example because that is the root of the issue.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Correct; echo 0; exit; shockingly doesn't work either on my server.

Comment: How about `echo (int)0;`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: `echo (int)0;` doesn't help, but as you can expect `echo (int)0;echo (int)0;` gives us `00`. (Just like `echo 0; echo 0;` did)

Comment: I'm out of ideas. See if you can contact that host and report it as a probable bug.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Will do. Again, I appreciate you trying for a reason with me!

Comment: This similar question might have something to do with it, and probably some server setting too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948663/php-get-bool-to-echo-false-when-false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Seems** to be a problem with ipage's host.  This is my current workaround. This workaround echoes 00 instead of 0, and the correct integer with no leading 0 otherwise.

```
if(empty($count[0])) echo 0; // Don't get why we need this--not needed on 000webhost, e.g.
echo $count[0];
```

***Update: confirmed bug on ipage's end***

Comment: This is not usual behavior. You should contact ipage for support.

Comment: @smcjones: I've contacted them, and I'm awaiting a reply.  If they get back to me, I'll be sure to follow up!