# feof function not returning false before the end of file

Tags: php

**i write php script for check feof function
according to php.net Returns TRUE if the file pointer is at EOF or an error occurs (including socket timeout); otherwise returns FALSE.
my question is there is no eturn value for feof() when there is before the end of file ?**

this is my php file

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one line until end-of-file


echo "----------------------<br>";
echo "end of file is ".feof($myfile)."<br>";
echo "---------------------<br>";


while(!feof($myfile))
{
   echo fgets($myfile) . " ----- "."end of file is ".feof($myfile)."<br>";
}

echo "----------------------<br>";
echo "end of file is ".feof($myfile)."<br>";
echo "---------------------<br>";

fclose($myfile)

?>
```

this text file(webdictionary.txt)

> AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML
>  
>   CSS = Cascading Style Sheets
>  
>   HTML = Hyper Text Markup Language
>   PHP = PHP Hypertext Preprocessor
>  
>   SQL= Structured Query Language SVG = Scalable Vector Graphics
>  
>   XML = EXtensible Markup Language

this is php output

```
----------------------
end of file is 
---------------------
AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML ----- end of file is 
CSS = Cascading Style Sheets ----- end of file is 
HTML = Hyper Text Markup Language ----- end of file is 
PHP = PHP Hypertext Preprocessor ----- end of file is 
SQL = Structured Query Language ----- end of file is 
SVG = Scalable Vector Graphics ----- end of file is 
XML = EXtensible Markup Language ----- end of file is 1
----------------------
end of file is 1
---------------------
```

Comment: `feof()` returns a boolean value (`true` or `false`). Echoing it will produce `"1"` for `true` and `""` for `false`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Get bool to echo false when false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948663/php-get-bool-to-echo-false-when-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is invalid. `false` echos out as an empty string, and `true` echos out as `1`.