# How to output php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am struggling on an AJAX call I make to let me read out the return value. My php code returns automatically an echo with `false` or `true`, which I made to check if the mail was send. But I am struggling to read out the value and get it to work.

Here is my AJAX code

```
if(proceed == true){            
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : 'inc/actions/sendmail.php',
        data    : $('#sentMessage').serialize(),
        cache   : false,
        dataType: 'text',
        success : function (data) 
        { 
            if (data == 'true'){
                $("#sentMessage")[0].reset();
                $("#err").append("<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Bedankt voor je bericht, wij nemen binnenkort contact met je op.</div>");
                $('input[name=name]').css('border-color','')
                $('input[name=email]').css('border-color','')
                $('textarea[name=message]').css('border-color','')
                setTimeout(function(){$('#err').fadeOut();}, 5000);
            }else{
                $("#err").append("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Je telefoonnummer bestaat niet uit 10 cijfers.</div>");
                $('input[name=phone]').css({'border':'2px solid red'});
                setTimeout(function(){$('#err').fadeOut();}, 5000); 
            }
        },
        error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log(errorThrown);}
    }); 
}
```

As you figure, it will push out the else statement constantly, cause it doesn't pass the if statement, since it doesn't know what to check.

Comment: Add console.log(data); right before your conditional. Then inspect the results of your data object. Chances are it's not just a simple boolean. If it is a boolean, then try changing your conditional to if(data) instead of if(data == 'true').

Comment: Use `console.log( data );` as the first statement inside the `success` handler so you can see what's being returned. May be you may need to use `if( data.trim() == 'true' ) ...`

Comment: May be this question/answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948663/php-get-bool-to-echo-false-when-false

Comment: actually, i use an echo within the php, not a boolean. Thansk for the tip though on console, slipped my mind. It does indeed tell me `true` as what is returned.

Comment: You don't show what the actual output of your PHP script is.  Whatever the case, make sure you use `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Brad Just to know: Why need `json_encode` when only echoing a single word?

Comment: @sri You technically don't, but inevitably these things grow.  For instance, what happens when the call fails?  Maybe you want to tell the user why it failed, and a simple boolean isn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though all you're outputting is `true/false` from your PHP script, and even after you've confirmed that `console.log( data )` outputs `true/false`, there may be white spaces around the string. Therefore you may want to use:

```
if( data.trim() == 'true' ) { ....

if( data.indexOf('true') > -1 ) { ..... //<=== OR
```

Just to confirm, you may want to use:

```
console.log( "'" + data + "'" );
```

Comment: That did the trick, I think indeed there was a whitespace involved. I will check the php file for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try console.log(data) to check exactly what your server is returning. There is also a change it is an object that is being returned, so you may need console.log(JSON.stringify(data)).

Also, this probably is not related but you should always be using triple equals (===), it is good practice in JavaScript.