# As3 Sending email using PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I'm using flash CS6 and flash player 11.4

Here is the example sending email from **Flash** using **PHP**

as3 code:

```
var php_file = "simple_email.php";
var message_text = "Hello Im mesage from flash.";

function sendEmail():void
{
   var myData:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
   myData.msg = message_text;

   var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(php_file);
   myRequest.data = myData;
   myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    try {

        loader.load(myRequest);

    } catch (error:Error) {

        trace("Unable to load URL");
    }

    function completeHandler(e:Event):void {

      trace("Data Content:"+e.target.data)
      trace("Response:"+e.target.data.success);
    };
};

sendEmail();
```

php code:

```
<?php
    $msg = $_POST["msg"];
    $to = "webhosting4@outlook.com";
    $subject="Message from php";
    $success = mail($to,$subject,$msg,"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    echo "temp=1&success=".$success;
?>
```

all is look simple, but not working

1) the **Response:** should be true or false and is:**".$success;
?>** (bad parsing?)

2) e.target.data looks strange:

```
Data Content:success=%22%20%24success%3B%0D%0A%3F%3E&%3C%3Fphp%0D%0A%09%24msg%20=%20var%5Fexport%28%24%5FPOST%2C%20true%29%3B%0D%0A%09%24to%20%3D%20%22baca%2Erene%40gmail%2Ecom%22%3B%0D%0A%09%24subject%3D%22Message%20from%20php%22%3B%0D%0A%09%24success%20%3D%20mail%28%24to%2C%24subject%2C%24msg%2C%22Content%2DType%3A%20text%2Fplain%3B%20charset%3Dutf%2D8%22%29%3B%0D%0A%09echo%20%22temp%3D1
```

3) After executing code I not received any email....something must be wrong?

Comment: You have a problem in your web server (if you have one of course) because php is not executed. You should know that you can not run a php script without a web server.

Answer (score 0):

In order:

1. [In PHP Booleans do not echo out "true" or "false" like they do in actionscript-3s trace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948663/php-get-bool-to-echo-false-when-false). You need to use some form of if statement in PHP to echo an appropriate string rather echoing the variable directly.
2. `e.target.data` is returning an utf escaped string version of your PHP code, this is usually a sign that php isn't executing and the file is just being read as a string, you should check your server is configured correctly and check the PHP error log (and alter your [php config to write all errors to the log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file))
3. Yes, something is wrong, check your PHP configs and error logs, quite likely and SMTP config error.

You can also use `error_get_last();` in php to pull the last error thrown by php.

Comment: I think that @Orien is trying to execute a local php script without even a web server.

Comment: Not having a webserver might be the root cause, but it doesn't provide an explanation of point one (which wouldn't work even with a webserver) or point two (which is confusion over utf character escaping)

Comment: In reality, his php code is fine just because there is no web server to execute it, flash will load it as any text file. Echo PHP boolean gives 1 or 0.

Comment: That seems to contradict the Q&A I linked in point one, do you have a source for that? (I don't have a server to hand to test it) although on second look at e.target.data, it is all the php code not a section as I first thought, which makes your point more likely, editing my answer now

Comment: I didn't mean simply `echo $var; `, of course if `$var` is `false` we will get nothing, I meant using the appropriate manner like `echo intval($var);`, for example, which gives 1 or 0 for a boolean.

Comment: @Orien I don't understand your last note, what do you mean by "but this return me intval($var); without execute" ?

Comment: thanks for you answers guys,
[akmozo]
you are right, I'm try to execute this app localy.
return value 1 or 0 should be enough, but this return me intval($var); without result. 
maybe it is because as [CyanAngel] says that php isn't executing. 
That mean I cant use error_get_last(), error_log("You messed up!", 3, "/php-error.log"); because php is not executing , only retunr his content as string....

Comment: when i add in php this line echo intval($success) I got Response:undefined;

Comment: when i add in php this line echo "temp=1&success=".intval($success); I got Response:".intval($success);

?>

Comment: @Orien First, you have to install a web server, you can not execute a php script directly, flash will consider it as any text file, that's why you will get always the script code in your response.

Comment: @Akmozo that should be the reason, I will do as you say. Many thanks :-)