# Laravel translate boolean values for validation (required_if)

Tags: laravel, internationalization, laravel-validation

Using this code inside my `validation.php`, I was able to translate the translate the values of the `edit_type`-field:

```
'values' => [
    'edit_type' => [
        '1' => 'Intern',
        '2' => 'Kunde'
    ],
    'every_day' => [
        'true' => 'ausgewählt',
        'false' => 'nicht ausgewählt'
    ]
],
```

But for some reason, the same logic does not work for the `every_day` field. I assume it has something to do with the values being booleans.

This is usually used with `required_if` inside the validation, in the case of `every_day` I use `required_unless` which should not make a difference.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: try `'every_day' => [
        '1' => 'ausgewählt',
        '0' => 'nicht ausgewählt'
    ]` 1 for true and 0 for false

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37179857)

> ... in PHP, the boolean value true is displayed as 1 and the boolean value false is displayed as the empty string (i.e. nothing is displayed)

So, you can map boolean values like this

```
'values' => [
    'every_day' => [
        '1' => 'ausgewählt',
        '' => 'nicht ausgewählt',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think this will help

```
'values' => [
'edit_type' => [
    '1' => 'Intern',
    '2' => 'Kunde'
],
'every_day' => [
    true => 'ausgewählt',
    false => 'nicht ausgewählt'
]
],
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about validation file.?

Comment: What do you need to know? It's the standard Laravel validation.php file in the lang folder.

Comment: @molerat For **every_day** field, which form element you have selected?

Comment: It is a checkbox (with VueJS). So it will send true/false to the backend.